# Android - OnClickListener in Adapter for GridView

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, onclicklistener

I'm using a GridView to show a list of "vehicles" (a rectangle displaying some short informations about the vehicle) and when i click on a rectangle, it expands the view to show more informations.
That's works fine.
But when i want to rebuild my gridview with other datas, the clicks aren't caught anymore by the gridview's childs.
I didn't want to use some onItemClickListener because it's just a show/hide feature on childs...
So I set onClickListener in the getView() function of my custom adapter.
Here's my adapter code :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.encart_vehicule, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.libVehi);
        vh.text2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.heureEngagement);
        vh.back = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.backcolor);
        vh.listEq = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.equipage);
        vh.vIndicator = (View) rowView.findViewById(R.id.view1);
        vh.more = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.more);

        vh.vIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vh.listEq.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (mlistMoyenMateriel.get(position).getLstPersonnels().size() == 0) {
            vh.more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!vh.opened) {
                        vh.more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        vh.vIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        vh.listEq.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        vh.more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        vh.vIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        vh.listEq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    vh.opened = !vh.opened;
                }
            });
        }

        vh.back.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"
                + mlistMoyenMateriel.get(position).getEtat()
                        .getm_strColor()));

        for (Personnel p : mlistMoyenMateriel.get(position)
                .getLstPersonnels()) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
            tv.setText(p.getm_strNom() + " " + p.getm_strPrenom() + " "
                    + p.getm_strMatricule());
            Resources r = getContext().getResources();
            float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, r.getDisplayMetrics());
            tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, (int) px);
            vh.listEq.addView(tv);
        }
        rowView.setTag(vh);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(mlistMoyenMateriel.get(position).getType()
            + " "
            + mlistMoyenMateriel.get(position).getNumeroOrdre()
                    .substring(1) + " "
            + mlistMoyenMateriel.get(position).getCode_centre());
    holder.text2.setText(dateUtil.Date_heureToString(mlistMoyenMateriel
            .get(position).getdEngagement(), "dd MMMMMMMM HH:mm")
            + (mlistMoyenMateriel.get(position).getDureeASLL() == null ? ""
                    : "+" + mlistMoyenMateriel.get(position).getDureeASLL()
                            + "mn"));

    holder.back.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"
            + mlistMoyenMateriel.get(position).getEtat().getm_strColor()));

    // holder.back.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+mlistMoyenMateriel.get(position).getEtat().getm_strColor()));

    return rowView;
}
```

Then my gridView instantiation :

```
    GridView gv = null;
    gv = (GridView) rlInter
            .findViewById(R.id.listAutresVehiculesEngages);
    gv.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
    MoyenMaterielAdapter mma = new MoyenMaterielAdapter(this,
            inter.getm_lstListeDesobjetVehiculePourCetteOperation());
    gv.setAdapter(mma);
    gv.invalidateViews();
```

When i recall this code a second time, the list is correctly rebuilt but, even if it pass in the "rowView.setOnClickListener" from the getView function, the clicks on childs does not have effect anymore (it did not expand my views). I tried to make a Toast on the click event, it is not show anymore too.

Does anyone knows about this issue? What I am doing wrong? I could try with a OnItemClickListener, but I think it will be a little bit too much for that little feature, knowing that still works but only the first time...
Thanks for your help!

(i'm really sorry for my english)

EDIT:
I missed something : at the second time it did NOT pass in the setOnClickListener code. Even if I got the new items displayed.

Comment: I figured out my issue, the top-top layout (a relative layout) was not cleared before the entire rebuilt of my sublayout (which include my gridview). Now, i clear it first before rebuilding all my views, and the top layout stoped catching my clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Add as first line in onClick() `ViewHolder vh =(ViewHolder)v.getTag();`.

Comment: Your 'v' is my 'rowView', so if rowView is null, rowView.getTag() will throw a NullPointerException...
And, as you can see in my code, i'v already used the getTag() after my rowView has been built.

Comment: Indeed. That's what will happen when v is null. Do not use rowView. Why you did? Use v.getTag(). Strange that in OnClick(View v) the v would be null. Never saw that before. Hard to believe.

Comment: Ok, i got confuse with your v, but i got it! Your were talking about the onClick parameter, i was thinking of my getView parameter.. Sorry! I figured out my issue, the top-top layout (a relative layout) was not cleared before the entire rebuilt of my sublayout (which include my gridview). Now, i clear it first before rebuilding all my views, and the top layout stoped catching my clicks.

Comment: Well just read my answer again then. But.... does it work now? I like to know. You forgot to tell.

Comment: Yes it works after i called removeAllViews from my gridview's top parent. My data set change at all, so i just used to rebuild my gridview with a new instance of my custom adapter. But that wasn't enough, i had to remove all views from parent first, then rebuild all child views, including my gridview. For some reason, at the rebuild, the clicks events were not dispached to the top view's childs.

Answer (score 0):

`rowView` is only `null` the first time your list loads.

Move your onclick to outside the `if (rowView == null)` block. Also, it is recommended to use the holder pattern in list adapters.

Comment: It's actually a holder pattern (that's why there's  `if (rowView == null) ` statement). I tried to put the setOnClickListener outside (even if it's not really good for performances because it will recall this code at each redraw), that does not work better.